# SQL copy paste a column to another table: "Subquery returned more than 1 value."

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, set

I just want to copy and paste a column in table A into table B.

I checked the two tables have same row count

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cube]
ADD [peer_group] int

--check row count same
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[cube]
--13103507

SELECT TOP 10
        peer_group
    FROM [dbo].[cube]
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL
--NULL

SELECT COUNT(group_5)
    FROM [dbo].[v_group]
--13103507

SELECT TOP 10
        group_5
    FROM [dbo].[v_group]
--1
--1
--2
--2
--3
--3
--4
--4
--4
--4
```

And I use `SET`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[cube]
SET [peer_group] = 
                (SELECT [group_5]
                FROM [dbo].[v_group]
                )
```

But it throws error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Any one know how to fix this please? Thank you!

Sorry I can conveniently post my data here. Please let me know if it's needed, and I'll simulate some data.

---

UPDATE:
Based on the answers/comments(thank you!) I understand the error occurred because SQL thought I want to put the many values retrieved in the `SELECT` subquery into each row of the empty new column [peer_group].

It seems `SET [column_1] = [column_2]` works only when both columns are in the same table, or in a joined table (see @Praveen 's solution).

Considering my specific situation that `[dbo].[v_group]` was a view generated from `[dbo].[cube]`. I'll just use

```
SELECT  *
        ,_something_ AS [peer_group] --this is what I had in [dbo].[v_group]
    INTO [dbo].[new]
    FROM [dbo].[cube]
```

Comment: The problem is obvious (what part of the error message do you not understand?).  However, what you want to do is not obvious.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: what is relation ship between [v_group] and cube table use that in join and do update

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff, I want to make column_1 in table_A exactly same as column_2 in table_B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try;

```
Update a
set a.[peer_group] = b.[group_5]
from [dbo].[cube] a
join [dbo].[v_group] b on a.id = b.id;
```

The error is due to the sub-query return more than one value for update.
You need to join these two tables do the update.